# how attach import javascript to window

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I am trying to import the javascript plugin FullCalendar in a Laravel webpack with:

```js
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
```

Then I compile this to my `app.js` file.
Then I try to run the calendar:

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script>
    let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
        }
    });
</script>
```

But then I get an error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined**

When I try to attach the calendar on a window, it doesn't work:

```
// does NOT work
window.Calendar = Calendar;
window.dayGridPlugin = dayGridPlugin;
```

How can I make this working?

Comment: Is the import in the app.js file?

Comment: yes it is. And the calendar initialize is on the page. I shall update my code.

Comment: When you are using webpack, you are building Javascript on the server but `window` is provided by the browser. As in Chinh Nguyễn's answer, simple copy the `Calendar` object into the `window`. Or, as is proper, write your code within the same file where you import.

Answer (score 1):

other approach: declare a function to callback inside app.js because jquery document ready is execute after that.
inside  .js source file:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

window.Calendar = Calendar;
window.dayGridPlugin = dayGridPlugin;
$(function(){
    ...
    if(window.initCalendar) {window.initCalendar()}
})
```

in view:

```
<script src="app.js">/script>
<script>
    function initCalendar(){
        let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined

This happens usually because script executes before your `app.js` file completely loaded. Therefore you have to wait until your `js` file fully loaded into your `html` file. You can add a event listener to overcome the problem.

Try these solutions:

In Vanilla.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Initialize calendar and bind the class into window
})
```

In jquery

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Initialize calendar and bind the class into window
});
```

Note: In jquery `$(document).ready()` will not work, because it executes code when DOM is loaded, rather than waiting for the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use FullCalendar inside app.js. If you absolutely want to write your code in another `script` tag, `export` what you need to use from outside:

```
export { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
export { default as dayGridPlugin } from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
```

Also, you have to add some build options in order to properly package as [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) in a specific namespace and in a specific JavaScript file:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["css-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
    output: {
        library: 'someLibName',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        filename: 'someLibName.js',
        auxiliaryComment: 'Test Comment',
      },
  };
```

Don't forget to `npm install --save-dev css-loader` if you don't already have it.

Then use FullCalendar in your own `script` tag like this:

```
const { Calendar, dayGridPlugin } = someLibName;

// Your own code that uses Fullcalendar
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use in javascript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
// your file is here
})
```

and in jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      // your file is here 
    });
});
```